# Auto add to toolbox of custom controls in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, toolbox

In Visual Studio 2008 there is a feature that automatically adds a toolbox pane and adds the custom controls which are in my web application project or in a class library in my current solution.

On another pc this is not working and I would like to know which setting I have to enable, probably in Tools | Options..., for this.

I am not looking for answers like: right click on the toolbox and then choose Add items.. I know how to do this but I am looking for the autodetect and add functionality in Visual Studio 2008 and to enable it on another pc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure if if this is what you are looking for, but in the Options dialog under the **Windows Forms Designer** item you can find a property in the grid that is called ***AutoToolboxPopulate***.

Set it to `true` to let VS automatically add your custom controls to the tool box.