# How to remove user control entries from toolbox in Visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

There are dozens of user control in our project. All these controls load into the Toolbox. I think this slows down the system when we work with the designer. Is this true? If so, then how to remove these controls from the Toolbox?

Comment: Found answers here


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534150/auto-add-to-toolbox-of-custom-controls-in-visual-studio

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288047/user-controls-not-showing-up-in-the-toolbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either delete the tab they are all in by right clicking and "Delete Tab".

Or just right click on the item itself and "Delete"

Ive persoanlly never noticed a slow down and ive all the Telerik ASP.NET set and quite a few custom ones in certain projects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found solution here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534150/auto-add-to-toolbox-of-custom-controls-in-visual-studio

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288047/user-controls-not-showing-up-in-the-toolbox

Answer (score 14):

If you want to prevent certain usercontrols in your project from being auto-added to the toolbox, then you can add the `[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]` attribute to your usercontrol class (*This syntax assumes you're using C#*).

Answer (score 6):

This will definitely slow down VS if there are a lot of projects all containing user controls.

Answer from linked questions:

Check this setting:

Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > General : AutoToolboxPopulate

It should be set to FALSE.