# Richtext editor control or component for winforms that looks/behaves like tiny MCE

Tags: winforms, controls, richtext

I am looking for a free Richtext editor that functions like the TinyMCE editor but for a winforms app

The most important part is that it must implement a editor toolbar so that the user does not need to learn a markup language

Comment: Shouldn't this be on super-user?

Comment: No, he's asking about an embeddable editor *control*. Like http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/

Comment: Do you have particular requirements?  Cost?  capabilities?  Are you looking for reviews? These controls exist, you can search for them.  So what are your particular requirements?

Comment: It seems the name of the control type I am looking for is a WYSIWYG editor for winforms

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about has been around for a looong time.

I found an [old, free control on softpedia](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/WinForms-Library.shtml).  It doesn't install into the VS2008 toolbox, but you can do that manually, or [configure Visual Studio to make it happen automagically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534150/auto-add-to-toolbox-of-custom-controls-in-visual-studio).

Here's a look at the designer experience.  Looks like Word 2000, probably because of the time it was published.

[image]

[Craig Andera posted one](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog) in 2004, too.  Haven't tried it, and haven't seen a picture of it.

[DevExpress has a commercial one](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/).

There are many, many others.

Comment: Have a look at the first line of my question  i am looking for something that is free , I already know of and use DevExpress , but I cant justify the cost for one control