# C# UserControl within one binary

Tags: c#, user-controls

I created two UserControls and a Windows.Form. UserControl #1 uses UserControl #2 and UserControl #1 is used in the Form. Is it possible to have all of those Controls in one binary instead of multiple control libraries and still have them available from the toolbox at design time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Auto add to toolbox of custom controls in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534150/auto-add-to-toolbox-of-custom-controls-in-visual-studio)